# How do I fade an overlaying div out to then increase the opacity of another div behind on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

So what I want to do is fade an overlaying 'intro' div out on-click, so that the person can access the div underneath. I am no master at jQuery AT ALL, so I really need help with this. My code is:

```
 <!-- OVERLAY  INTRO  -->
<div class="button animated slideInLeft"  id="introbox"  style="width:1000px;"  align="center">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p class="secondaryheadertext">Blah blah blah</p>
    <div align="center">
        <img title="Cofffee Bean" src="images/cfblogo1.png" id="cfblogo1">
    </div>
    <!-- UNDERLAYING MAIN BIT  -->
    <div id="main">
        [WHATEVER IS BEHIND GOES IN HERE]
    </div>
```

Comment: It's really simple, you want to fade out this div right? Have you searched the internet for fading out a div with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a reference to jquery in your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then in your script block just add the following code. this is assuming you want to click the introbox to fade.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#introbox').on('click', function(){
       $(this).fadeOut('slow');
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks guys and especially @Sushil you helped me out a lot! (im the guy who made this post)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the trick?

```
$(function(){
    var $intro = $("#introbox");
    $(document).bind('click', function(){
        $intro.fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvcnrjeq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#introbox').click(function(){
       $(this).fadeOut('slow');
   });
});
</script>
```